# host header url for linux web server

Tags: apache-httpd, dns

I am running a webpage on Apache at my vps(Debian) with the url of http://vps.foo.com/stuff.html. How can I change it so that the url is only stuff.foo.com? I use to do this in IIS many years ago, not sure how to do it in Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not as simple as it may seem.

1. You need the subdomain `stuff`, so that you can use the address `stuff.foo.com`. You should register it by your DNS server - create a DNS entry for it. Otherwise people won't be able to find it.
2. Then in your Apache you need either a redirection from `vps.foo.com/stuff.html` to `stuff.foo.com` or you can move the resources straight at `stuff.foo.com`. But then you won't be able to reach them at the old address.

Comment: OK, I know how to do the DNS, but how would I go about the redirection on Apache?

Comment: @SilverSurfer https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#Redirect Notice, this is just setting up an alias. It would still direct at `vps.foo.com/stuff.html`. If you don't want `vps.foo.com` at all, you need to rebuild the site at the new subdomain and set `stuff.html` as index of `stuff.foo.com`.